# How % operator works when we use negative values for operation?

Tags: operators

When I'm trying to execute -13%-10 statement in c , I'm getting -3 as output, I'm curious to know that why the output is not 3.

Comment: Well, I found the answer, and here it is,
Actually I was thinking its will be  be solved as -13 % -10 = -13/-10
=13/10=10*1+3
but actually it will be solveed as

Comment: Finally I found the answer, and here it is,
Actually I was thinking it will be  be solved as -13 % -10  by cancelling the negative signs and then calculating the remainder as 13 - 10*1 = 3
but actually it will be solved as
-13 % -10 = -13 - (-10*1)= -13 +10 =-3

Answer (score 0):

I did not know the answer to your question, either.  So I expanded your original equation and inserted them into a short Netbeans/GCC C program:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Colleen
 *
 * Created on December 16, 2015, 9:43 AM
 * Testing modulus operations with negative numbers.
 */

#include <windef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    INT16 A = -13;
    INT16 B = -10;

    printf ("1. %3d %% %3d = %3d\n",  A,  B,   A %  B);
    printf ("2. %3d %% %3d = %3d\n", -A,  B, (-A)%  B);
    printf ("3. %3d %% %3d = %3d\n",  A, -B,   A%(-B));
    printf ("4. %3d %% %3d = %3d\n", -A, -B, (-A)%(-B));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here were my results:

```
1. -13 % -10 =  -3
2.  13 % -10 =   3
3. -13 %  10 =  -3
4.  13 %  10 =   3

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 35ms)
```

So it looks to me like the dividend (the number you are dividing, or "A" above) and the quotient (the answer, or "C" above) will always have the same sign.